# how to plot number of valid rows with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, count

With a dataframe as

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
             class = c("a1", "a1", "a1", "b1", "b1"),
             var1 = c("S", "S", "R", "S", "S"),
             var2 = c("S", "R", NA, NA, "R"),
             var3 = c(NA, "R", "R", "S", "S"))
```

I would like to plot the number of rows without NAs for var1 from var3.

One way I found is to generate another dataframe as

```
df_count <- matrix(nrow=3, ncol=2)
df_count <- as.data.frame(df_count)
names(df_count) <- c("var_num", "count")
df_count$var_num <- as.factor(names(df)[3:5])
for (i in 1:3) {
    df_count[i,2] <- sum(!is.na(df[,i+2]))
}
```

and then plot as

```
ggplot(df_count, aes(x=var_num, y=count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Is there an easier way to choose var1 through var3 and count the valid rows without generating a new dataframe?

Comment: You'll need to reshape to long regardless, but `geom_bar`'s `stat_count` can aggregate for you, e.g. `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(var, val, starts_with('var')) %>% drop_na(val) %>% ggplot(aes(var, fill = val)) + geom_bar()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')

df <- melt(df, id.vars = c('name', 'class'))  # melt data
df <- df[!is.na(df$value), ]                  # remove NA
df <- with(df, aggregate(df, by = list(variable), FUN = length )) # compute length by grouping variable

ggplot(df, aes( x = Group.1, y = value, fill = Group.1 )) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

## stacked bar

```
df <- melt(df, id.vars = c('name', 'class'))  # melt data
df <- df[!is.na(df$value), ]                  # remove NA
df <- with(df, aggregate(df, by = list(variable, value), FUN = length )) # compute length by grouping variable and value

ggplot(df, aes( x = Group.1, y = value, fill = Group.2 )) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 class = c("a1", "a1", "a1", "b1", "b1"),
                 var1 = c("S", "S", "R", "S", "S"),
                 var2 = c("S", "R", NA, NA, "R"),
                 var3 = c(NA, "R", "R", "S", "S"))
```